# why do i get numba "did not contain a loop with signature matching types" error?

Tags: python, numba, signature

I get an error when using a vectorize numba function:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\maxime\Desktop\SESAME\PycharmProjects\neocom\di.py", line 46, in 
> o = find_intersection_high_vectorize(0., 100., 20., 80., 10., 20., 5.)
> numpy.core._exceptions._UFuncNoLoopError: ufunc 'find_intersection_high_vectorize' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (<class 'numpy.dtype[float64]'>, <class 'numpy.dtype[float64]'>, <class 'numpy.dtype[float64]'>, <class 'numpy.dtype[float64]'>, <class 'numpy.dtype[float64]'>, <class 'numpy.dtype[float64]'>, <class 'numpy.dtype[float64]'>) -> None

I don't understand it because the signature seems correct to me. However, the signaure of the error message seems to return a None which does not make sense since I put a float64 as a return type.

here's a minimal example:

```
from numba import vectorize, float64

@vectorize([float64(float64, float64, float64, float64, float64, float64, float64)])
def find_intersection_high_vectorize(S_z0, S_z1, T_z0, T_z1, r1, r2, d):
    # h = np.minimum(S_z1, T_z1) - np.maximum(S_z0, T_z0)
    # commented computations
    # else:
    return 0.
 
o = find_intersection_high_vectorize(0., 100., 20., 80., 10., 20., 5.)
print(o)
```

Comment: It works fine with Numba 55.1: there is no error and the function returns 0.0. Please consider updating your version.

Comment: I've got the 0.56 one

Comment: Strange, I got the same thing with the 0.56 (ie. no error, tested on Windows with CPython 3.9.6). What is the result of `find_intersection_high_vectorize.types` and `find_intersection_high_vectorize.targetoptions` on your machine?